# skip @testing-library when running npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

Are there someway to skip install `@testing-library*` by running `npm install`
I have docker container and my `package-lock.json` has more than 4000 rows. Is it someway to skip install the `@testing-library*`

```
FROM node:17.5

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
...
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

i want to skip the installation of

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is move your testing dependencies to devDependencies in package.json like:

```
devDependencies: {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0"
}
```

And while installation in docker, run `npm install --production` instead of `npm install`